# Control flow not getting into variable declaration

Tags: c#, variables, declaration

For my task I am just updating the existing functionality in cs file, with one more new flag to monitor sending mail function.
Current function is,

```
public static string EditDetails(AccountDetails Account, string[] existingAccount)
{
    // some code goes here

    var enableNewWelcomeMail = true; // control not getting here..
    var isAccountUpdated = true;
    var isMailSent = true;

    if (Account.ContractType == ContractType.Licensed) // even though condition true value is not assigned to false
    {
        enableNewWelcomeMail = false;
    }
    // remaining code goes here
}
```

After adding the new flag variable I have cleaned the project and built it. Even now the control just skips the variable declaration. While cleaning and building the project I have noticed one warning message as

> warning CS0219: The variable 'enableNewWelcomeMail' is assigned but its value is never used

For some other variables also I am seeing this warning message but those are working fine only.
Any suggestion regarding this would be really helpful.

Comment: Where is ExistingAccout declared? BTW should probably be ExistingAccount. If the code is not getting to your variable declaration, then it is probably exiting or getting an exception in the part you labeled "some code goes here"

Comment: what is `ExistingAccout` here.. ?

Comment: Existing account which means already an account which is licensed too.

Comment: Can you show the code for `// some code goes here`?

Comment: In the snippet shown, the warning is correct and probably explains the issue: `enableNewWelcomeMail` is set but never read - i.e. no point setting it since you never use it anywhere... Is `enableNewWelcomeMail` the new flag you added?

Comment: No that part `// some code goes here` doesn't do anything here. I got it worked.
previously I have just declared the flag as true and based on the condition I have set false value to the flag. So that the flag value doesn't declared and control not covered the declaration statement. But now, I have used that flag value to regulate the flow. So now it is fine. 
Thanks @John, What you said is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the warning means exactly what it says. It is part of static code analysis and should help you with coding in two ways:

1. Optimize and clean up your code be removing unused code
2. Spot mistakes. Imagine you actually wanted to use the initial value but forgot to do so. In this case the warning will indicate something went wrong.

You assign a value to the variable that is never used. Look at the following example:

```
var valueUnused = false;
valueUnused = true;
valueUnused = false;
```

You see three assignments but 2 of the values are not used before they are overwritten. If you would use the value withing an `if (valueUnused)` block somewhere the warning would disappear. You could even do something like this:

```
var valueUnused = false;
valueUnused = !valueUnused;
valueUnused = !valueUnused;
```

And for the control flow my guess is that you are building for Release and the optimizer removes all this code for you for the above mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this type of warning is thrown when compiler finds that the second-assignment to the variable is always overwriting the value of the first-assignment(through static-code analysis).

This means that your if-statement is always true.

That is the reason of your warning. It doesn't mean what you think.

```
if (Account.ContractType == ContractType.Licensed) 
// your if-condition is always true, that is why this warning is displayed
{
    enableNewWelcomeMail = false;
}
```

enableNewWelcomeMail will always be false, such is your if-condition. This is what the warning clarifies.